# Behavior of deployment tool in Visual Studio Express

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-express

I created a quick game in VS Express (2008) and used the built-in deployment tool (click once?) to create an installer.

I took it to another computer, ran it (Windows XP) to install from a burned CD.

It created the program but only for the logged in user.

Is there a setting I'm missing for installing it to all users on an XP system? Or is this a limitation of the Express edition's installer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a limitation of ClickOnce.  The retail edition allows you to create installers that will deploy your app for all users.  But the Express edition doesn't support Setup projects.  That's one of the ways they encourage you to pay for the license.

Backgrounder info is in this [blog post](http://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2009/09/07/installing-a-clickonce-application-for-all-users/).